# SharePoint 2007 : How to sign out user?

Tags: authentication, object-model, spcontext, spuser

I've an application build on SharePoint 2007 platform, the problem is in Mozilla FireFox, the sign out button does not successfully sign out the current login user, I believe SharePoint 2007 is not fully compatible with FireFox.

I think of a workaround by using SharePoint Object Modal to programmatically sign off the current login user (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser) on SignOut.aspx, is this possible?

Any reply is much appreciated. thank you.

**Update:**
Anyone has solution?? I've tried the approach from this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ff30c5dd-356f-48b9-a3b7-72d477d64d14
but the XMLHttpRequest.Abort() not working

**Update 2:**
I tried on a workaround by redirect the user to access denied page (/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=false) on SignOut.aspx, of cause, I also added JavaScript to check browser type, only redirect when it is non-IE browser, the AccessDenied.aspx page able to log out current sign in user by re-prompt sign in window.

The workaround work in my situation, since the objective is to cover the security issue for non-IE browser.

However, user will still need to close the browser for complete sign out

so far this is the less effort workaround I can think of, it is open for any comment and suggestion :)

Comment: ya we all know that this feature working fine in IE but not in Firefox, just why I post the question to ask for workaround

Comment: Don't forget to mark the post that worked out for you as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

In IE (version > 6) SignOut.aspx uses ClearAuthenticationCache as a client side command. This does not work for Firefox.

I found this example on StackOverflow that might work for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326/is-there-a-browser-equivalent-to-ies-clearauthenticationcache

Answer (score 1):

Yea, Sign out only works correctly in IE.  In order to successfully sign out in other browsers you need to close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I attempted to do this and determined that to programmatically remove a Firefox log-in without the browser you had to do some crazy stuff like clearing cached credential info from the computer as well as standard web request removals, and had to assume the user would have the trust on the site set so that it would allow it.

Ultimately I determined it to be too infeasible and called it a flaw in the system and left it at that. I would recommend you do the same and save yourself a crazy headache.

Comment: yes you are right Zork, this matter has been border me for few days, unfortunately my client insist want to find a workaround for that. if any script able to close Firefox Browser when SignOut.aspx page load, then it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Like Steve said, some browsers have to be closed to log off completely.

Some configuration settings in your browser may have stored the credentials, so each time you go to the site, you are automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a browser, you're also creating a new session. Some browsers are able to close these sessions by themselfs, mostly by closing the explorer window. (Like Internet Explorer). A session contains all the information like PC-name, date, logged_in state, and so on. This session cannot be ended softly, only in a hard way like closing the webbrowser.

Too bad there is no other way (yet?) around this problem than adding it to your Trusted Websites.

Answer (score -1):

As all we know SharePoint is highly compatible with IE but it also supports cross browser platform. Few of the features are not supported in Mozilla, Chrome, etc. but fully supported in IE.

Yes you can always code a solution to clear the cache of the firebox browser. Try developing a custom timer job service in visual studio and schedule it to run after 30 mins (just an example, you may change this as per your requirement).

This timer job will keep checking if the user is logged in but is inactive then directly clear the cache.

Comment: Hi Zakir,thanks for your reply, wonder you have the sample code on clear the cache?

Comment: Clearing the cache is a client side operation. How would you solve that with a timer job?

Comment: Clearing cache is client-side operation and cannot be achieved with a Timer job.